# Access Data From youtube API

Tags: python-2.7, http, youtube-api, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap data from a youtube playlist using python. Following is the code

```
import requests,json
url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems? part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUG_tllpQfOKryGQiYCRxYEw&key={Your_API_KEY}"
r = requests.get(url)
response = json.loads(r.text)
```

But when I print it output is like below

```
{u'items': [], u'kind': u'youtube#playlistItemListResponse', u'etag': u'"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/E0c9LqWjuNHvL-UjCIKS4N9Fn5M"', u'pageInfo': {u'resultsPerPage': 50, u'totalResults': 0}}
```

Though If I try to access the same in https://developers.google.com I'm getting proper output as below

```
{"kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse","etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/GhvozdtV2OwhnBmMko_Ej0aqtMs\"","nextPageToken": "CGQQAA","prevPageToken": "CDIQAQ","pageInfo": {"totalResults": 1901,"resultsPerPage": 50},"items": [{........
```

Even if I try to access the URL in some browser, no data is coming up. Can someone shed me light on this?

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: Didn't get you..could you be more specific

Comment: @SandeepRajamahendravarapu is this your channel? when I enter to that channel I see no uploaded videos - probably all of their videos are *private* = hence, you cannot access to its *public* data= because there is none *publicly*. What are the parameters you supplied when requesting via https://developers.google.com?